# Get string type ( double or single quotes )

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect the data type and if that data type is string then check if 
it is double or single quotes.

Let say i have two strings:

```
var a = "hello";

var b = 'hello';
```

How can i detect if the string is double or single quotes in javascript???

I have tried to do so:

```
 typeof a
```

i get string as output....but i don't know if that string is double or single quotes. I have also searched a alot, but can't find how is that done.

Comment: sorry, but why do you even care?

Comment: I just want to understand it and to see if that is possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to detect the data type and if that data type is string then check if it is double or single quotes.

You can't, that information isn't retained in any way once parsing is complete. They're both just strings. They are completely indistinguishable.

The quotes are purely a source code thing. They say "The text here isn't code, it's the content of a string." Once the string is created at runtime, it's completely irrelevant what source code created it — including the type of quotes used, or even if it was the result of evaluating something else entirely (like a template literal or a function call).

Comment: That give sense, thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. :)